# Sonata ModelAutocompleteType Query/Callback

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

I'd like to use something like a `query_builder` for the `EntityType::class` so I can only display specific results.

I noticed according to the docs you can use callback but I was struggling to figure out how I'd apply this.

My working **EntityType** example:

```
'query_builder' => function (MyRepository $repository) use ($example) {
    return $repository->findByExampleBuilder($example);
}
```

This returns a query builder which works. How can I apply something similar to the ModelAutocompleteType callback?

Answer (score 0):

This documentation section might help you https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html use SonataAdminBundleFormTypeModelAutocompleteType.
As your question is hard to understand due to lack of context, you might also be interested in https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html doctrine_orm_model_autocomplete.